# colorbalance in an image using c++ and opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, colors

I'm trying to score the colorbalance of an image using c++ and opencv.

To do this the easiest way is to count the number of pixels in each color and then see if one of the colors is more prevalent.

I figured I should probably used calcHist and with the split function I can split a image in R, G, and B histograms. However I am unsure about what to do next. I could probably walk through all the bins and just see how many pixels are in there but this seems like a lot of work (I currently use 256 bins).

Is there a faster way to count the pixels in a color range? Also I am not sure how it would work if white or black are the more prevalant colors?

Answer (score 2):

Automatic color balance algorithm is described in this link http://web.stanford.edu/~sujason/ColorBalancing/simplestcb.html

For C++ Code you can refer to this link : https://www.morethantechnical.com/2015/01/14/simplest-color-balance-with-opencv-wcode/

```
/// perform the Simplest Color Balancing algorithm
void SimplestCB(Mat& in, Mat& out, float percent) {
    assert(in.channels() == 3);
    assert(percent > 0 && percent < 100);

    float half_percent = percent / 200.0f;

    vector<Mat> tmpsplit; split(in,tmpsplit);
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
        //find the low and high precentile values (based on the input percentile)
        Mat flat; tmpsplit[i].reshape(1,1).copyTo(flat);
        cv::sort(flat,flat,CV_SORT_EVERY_ROW + CV_SORT_ASCENDING);
        int lowval = flat.at<uchar>(cvFloor(((float)flat.cols) * half_percent));
        int highval = flat.at<uchar>(cvCeil(((float)flat.cols) * (1.0 - half_percent)));
        cout << lowval << " " << highval << endl;

        //saturate below the low percentile and above the high percentile
        tmpsplit[i].setTo(lowval,tmpsplit[i] < lowval);
        tmpsplit[i].setTo(highval,tmpsplit[i] > highval);

        //scale the channel
        normalize(tmpsplit[i],tmpsplit[i],0,255,NORM_MINMAX);
    }
    merge(tmpsplit,out);
}

// Usage example
void main() {
    Mat tmp,im = imread("lily.png");

    SimplestCB(im,tmp,1);

    imshow("orig",im);
    imshow("balanced",tmp);
    waitKey(0);
    return;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Bug in vector<Mat> tmpsplit; Must be vector<Mat> tmpsplit(3);

Answer (score 1):

Colour balance is normally looking at a white (or gray) surface and checking the ratios of red/blue to green. A perfectly balanced system would have equal signal levels in red/blue.

You can then simply work out the average red/blue from the test gray card image and apply the same scaling to your real image.

Doing it on a live image with no reference is trickier, you have to find areas that are probably white (ie bright and nearly r=g=b) and use them as the reference

Answer (score 1):

There's no definitive algorithm for colour balance, so anything you might implement, however good it is, will probably fail in some conditions.

One of the simplest algorithms is called Grey World, and assumes that statistically the average colour of a scene should be grey. And if it isn't, it means that it needs to be corrected to grey. So, very simply (in pseudo-python), if you have an image `RGB`:

```
cc[0] = np.mean(RGB[:,0]) # calculating channel-wise average
cc[1] = np.mean(RGB[:,1])
cc[2] = np.mean(RGB[:,2])
cc = cc / np.sqrt((cc**2).sum()) # normalise the light (you might want to
                                 # play with this a bit
RGB /= cc # divide every pixel by the estimated light
```

Note that here I'm assuming that `RGB` is an array of floats with values between 0 and 1. Something else that helps is to exclude from the average pixels that contain values below and above certain thresholds (e.g., below 0.05 and above 0.95). This way you ignore pixels whose value is heavily influenced by noise (small values) and pixels that saturated the camera sensor and whose colour may not be reliable (large values).